# Creating empty Polygons or SpatialPolygons in R?

Tags: polygon, r, polygon-creation, sp

I'm working on a project where I'm looking at overlap in users circling an area in an image. Esentially, I make a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame where each user gets one row. Some users don't select anything. So, I'm trying to figure out how to include that information. When I attempt to create a "NULL" polygon, and then scale it up, either with something like

`Polygon(matrix(rep(NA, 4), nrow=2)`

or

`Polygon(NULL)`

or anysuch, none of these work.

1) Can I create an empty polygon?
2) or add a row to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with no matching SpatialPolygons object?

Comment: FYI, you can create an empty Spatial Polygons object - SpatialPolygons(list())

Comment: And SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpatialPolygons(list()), data=data.frame())

Answer (score 3):

To create an empty SpatialPolygons object use  `SpatialPolygons(list())`

credit to jebyrnes, but I thought it should be posted as an answer not a comment.

Comment: Yup - but still #2 is elusive.