# Creating empty SpatialPoints or SpatialPointsDataFrame in R?

Tags: r, sp

I have been trying to create an empty SpatialPoints in R but have not found the way yet.

I have tried with this formula:

```
SpatialPoints(as.matrix(data.table(x = numeric(), y = numeric())))
```

But it didn't work.
The closest thing I have found on the internet is [Creating empty Polygons or SpatialPolygons in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224841) but that is for polygons and apparently it does not work the same way.

I have sp version 1.2.7

Comment: You should think about why you want to create this. If its to put in a `for` loop to incrementally add points to, you might be better off using an `apply`-type operation and then combining the results in the end - this is usually faster than growing a vector from an empty object.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `SpatialPoints` object with one row in it, and then drop it with `[-1,]`:

```
> zero = SpatialPoints(data.frame(x = 0, y = 0))[-1,]
> zero
SpatialPoints:
     x y
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA
```

Quick test to see what this thing is:

```
> length(zero)
[1] 0
> class(zero)
[1] "SpatialPoints"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

Comment: [temp_comment] by chance I found a duplicate account of yours (https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/3537/spacedman?tab=profile). Is it on purpose? If you are interested, you can merge them (https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a shorter way ...

```
new("SpatialPoints",                                                          
    coords = structure(numeric(0), .Dim = c(0L, 2L),                          
                       .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"))),  
    bbox = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(2L, 2L),                         
                     .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"),
                                      c("min", "max"))),
    proj4string = new("CRS", projargs = NA_character_)) 
# SpatialPoints:
#      coords.x1 coords.x2
# Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA
```